# Custom CollectionView Cell PrepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom UICollection View Cell. One of that cell's property's is `cellImageView`. When the user selects a cell, I want to pass the image from that view (`cellImageView.image`) to the next one. Here's what I've tried:

```
if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForCell(sender as! UICollectionViewCell)
{
    if segue.identifier == "show"
    {
        var segue = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewPhoto
        segue.imageURL = URLToPass

    }
}
```

but quickly realized that's the wrong route to take. What's the best way to go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: look perfectly fine to me, what do you think is wrong about it?

Comment: looks find to me as well, except for that variable name segue, which is ambiguous.

Comment: After going this route, there is no way to get the cellImageView.image

Comment: Also, my custom class for the cell is called GalleryClass, not sure if that's important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{ 
  if let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? GalleryClass
  {
    let imageToPass = cell.cellImageView.image
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(mySegue, sender: imageToPass)
  }
}
```

And in your **prepareForSegue** function:

```
if segue.identifier == "show"
{
  var segue = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewPhoto
  // segue.imageURL = URLToPass
  segue.image = sender as! UIImage
}
```

This way you're keeping code which contains **CollectionView** stuff in the own delegate method, which is easier to maintain if you have to change it in the future. And you only pass data in your **prepareForSegue** function which you actually need in there.

Comment: Any reason to use `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` rather than `didSelecteItemAtIndexPath` ?